# New kitchen sink replacement drain smells

Tags: plumbing

Replaced old double stainless sink with a new one. Plumbed into same wall drain, replaced new trap and pipe to wall. The only addition was I plumbed the dishwasher into drain between sink and trap. New tailpieces with sink are plastic, old was metal.
Any suggestions of fixing smell. I now have to keep plugs in the sink to stop smell.

Comment: Did you use an air gap or a high loop for the dishwasher drain?

Comment: You did run water after installing everything to fill the trap, right? Can you add a picture?

Comment: High loop and yes. How do I add picture?

Comment: Edit your post and  insert an image. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Answer (score 0):

You may know that a plumbing trap traps water in a loop which prevents sewer gas from flowing into the house. All drains must have a trap including the dishwasher. So the dishwasher discharge hose must be attached to the inlet side of a trap otherwise you get gassed.

Comment: He says as much in the question: "I plumbed the dishwasher into drain between sink and trap."